# SVG selectAll why only first element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I wanted to draw a bullet chart with fixed data but it only shows the first element. How can I show the rest?
And I can't use ".enter().append("svg")" because it won't show in Web Intelligence, where I want to integrate this chart

```html
<style>

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.bullet { font: 10px sans-serif; }
.bullet .marker { stroke: #000; stroke-width: 2px; }
.bullet .tick line { stroke: #666; stroke-width: .5px; }
.bullet .range.s0 { fill: #eee; }
.bullet .range.s1 { fill: #ddd; }
.bullet .range.s2 { fill: #ccc; }
.bullet .measure.s0 { fill: lightsteelblue; }
.bullet .measure.s1 { fill: steelblue; }
.bullet .title { font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; }
.bullet .subtitle { fill: #999; }

</style>
<button>Update</button>
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script>
(function() {

// Chart design based on the recommendations of Stephen Few. Implementation
// based on the work of Clint Ivy, Jamie Love, and Jason Davies.
// http://projects.instantcognition.com/protovis/bulletchart/
d3.bullet = function() {
  var orient = "left", // TODO top & bottom
      reverse = false,
      duration = 0,
      ranges = bulletRanges,
      markers = bulletMarkers,
      measures = bulletMeasures,
      width = 380,
      height = 30,
      tickFormat = null;

  // For each small multiple…
  function bullet(g) {
    g.each(function(d, i) {
      var rangez = ranges.call(this, d, i).slice().sort(d3.descending),
          markerz = markers.call(this, d, i).slice().sort(d3.descending),
          measurez = measures.call(this, d, i).slice().sort(d3.descending),
          g = d3.select(this);

      // Compute the new x-scale.
      var x1 = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, Math.max(rangez[0], markerz[0], measurez[0])])
          .range(reverse ? [width, 0] : [0, width]);

      // Retrieve the old x-scale, if this is an update.
      var x0 = this.__chart__ || d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, Infinity])
          .range(x1.range());

      // Stash the new scale.
      this.__chart__ = x1;

      // Derive width-scales from the x-scales.
      var w0 = bulletWidth(x0),
          w1 = bulletWidth(x1);

      // Update the range rects.
      var range = g.selectAll("rect.range")
          .data(rangez);

      range.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "range s" + i; })
          .attr("width", w0)
          .attr("height", height)
          .attr("x", reverse ? x0 : 0)
        .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("width", w1)
          .attr("x", reverse ? x1 : 0);

      range.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("x", reverse ? x1 : 0)
          .attr("width", w1)
          .attr("height", height);

      // Update the measure rects.
      var measure = g.selectAll("rect.measure")
          .data(measurez);

      measure.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "measure s" + i; })
          .attr("width", w0)
          .attr("height", height / 3)
          .attr("x", reverse ? x0 : 0)
          .attr("y", height / 3)
        .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("width", w1)
          .attr("x", reverse ? x1 : 0);

      measure.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("width", w1)
          .attr("height", height / 3)
          .attr("x", reverse ? x1 : 0)
          .attr("y", height / 3);

      // Update the marker lines.
      var marker = g.selectAll("line.marker")
          .data(markerz);

      marker.enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "marker")
          .attr("x1", x0)
          .attr("x2", x0)
          .attr("y1", height / 6)
          .attr("y2", height * 5 / 6)
        .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("x1", x1)
          .attr("x2", x1);

      marker.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("x1", x1)
          .attr("x2", x1)
          .attr("y1", height / 6)
          .attr("y2", height * 5 / 6);

      // Compute the tick format.
      var format = tickFormat || x1.tickFormat(8);

      // Update the tick groups.
      var tick = g.selectAll("g.tick")
          .data(x1.ticks(8), function(d) {
            return this.textContent || format(d);
          });

      // Initialize the ticks with the old scale, x0.
      var tickEnter = tick.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "tick")
          .attr("transform", bulletTranslate(x0))
          .style("opacity", 1e-6);

      tickEnter.append("line")
          .attr("y1", height)
          .attr("y2", height * 7 / 6);

      tickEnter.append("text")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("dy", "1em")
          .attr("y", height * 7 / 6)
          .text(format);

      // Transition the entering ticks to the new scale, x1.
      tickEnter.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", bulletTranslate(x1))
          .style("opacity", 1);

      // Transition the updating ticks to the new scale, x1.
      var tickUpdate = tick.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", bulletTranslate(x1))
          .style("opacity", 1);

      tickUpdate.select("line")
          .attr("y1", height)
          .attr("y2", height * 7 / 6);

      tickUpdate.select("text")
          .attr("y", height * 7 / 6);

      // Transition the exiting ticks to the new scale, x1.
      tick.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", bulletTranslate(x1))
          .style("opacity", 1e-6)
          .remove();
    });
    d3.timer.flush();
  }

  // left, right, top, bottom
  bullet.orient = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return orient;
    orient = x;
    reverse = orient == "right" || orient == "bottom";
    return bullet;
  };

  // ranges (bad, satisfactory, good)
  bullet.ranges = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return ranges;
    ranges = x;
    return bullet;
  };

  // markers (previous, goal)
  bullet.markers = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return markers;
    markers = x;
    return bullet;
  };

  // measures (actual, forecast)
  bullet.measures = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return measures;
    measures = x;
    return bullet;
  };

  bullet.width = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = x;
    return bullet;
  };

  bullet.height = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = x;
    return bullet;
  };

  bullet.tickFormat = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return tickFormat;
    tickFormat = x;
    return bullet;
  };

  bullet.duration = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return duration;
    duration = x;
    return bullet;
  };

  return bullet;
};

function bulletRanges(d) {
  return d.ranges;
}

function bulletMarkers(d) {
  return d.markers;
}

function bulletMeasures(d) {
  return d.measures;
}

function bulletTranslate(x) {
  return function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d) + ",0)";
  };
}

function bulletWidth(x) {
  var x0 = x(0);
  return function(d) {
    return Math.abs(x(d) - x0);
  };
}

})();


</script>
<svg>
<script>

var margin = {top: 5, right: 40, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 50 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var chart = d3.bullet()
    .width(width)
    .height(height);

d3.json('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4061961/raw/6eb742223b9795260ba62150196ed0ae4a461e39/bullets.json', function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

        
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg") 
  .data(data)
  // .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("class", "bullet")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(chart);
  
  
   var title = svg.append("g")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + height / 2 + ")");

  title.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.title; });

  title.append("text")
      .attr("class", "subtitle")
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.subtitle; });



  d3.selectAll("button").on("click", function() {
    svg.datum(randomize).call(chart.duration(1000)); // TODO automatic transition
  });
});

function randomize(d) {
  if (!d.randomizer) d.randomizer = randomizer(d);
  d.ranges = d.ranges.map(d.randomizer);
  d.markers = d.markers.map(d.randomizer);
  d.measures = d.measures.map(d.randomizer);
  return d;
}

function randomizer(d) {
  var k = d3.max(d.ranges) * .2;
  return function(d) {
    return Math.max(0, d + k * (Math.random() - .5));
  };
}

</script>


</svg>
```

Comment: Please make your snippet into a working example.

Comment: snippet is working now

Comment: swap the last two script tags

Comment: that doesn't matter